# Identify AC Power Cord with rotated pins

Tags: power-supply, power, connector

Is this AC power cord connector a standard one? The pins seems to be rotated 90 degrees.

This ATX power supply unit (Silverstone ST1500) did not come with the cord and I am hoping to be able to get the power cord off ebay/Amazon/Digikey once it can be identified

[image]

Comment: Region of use? Where did you order the supply from?

Comment: @Shamtam Its for use in America. Ordered off eBay in America.

Comment: These sockets are very common on say, APC UPS units, due to the extra power load needed.

Comment: If it had a standard connector and a cheap power cord was used, a fire could result due to overheating of the power cord or its connector.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I would hope that nobody would mfr a cable that claimed up to 16A, but was actually too small a gauge...

Answer (score 25, accepted):

It looks like it is C19/C20 type connector

[image]

from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEC_60320#C19.2FC20_coupler):

> Earthed, 16 A, polarized. This coupler is used for some IT applications where higher currents are required, as for instance, on high-power workstations and servers, uninterruptible power supplies, power distribution units, large network routers, switches, blade enclosures, and similar equipment. It is rectangular and has pins parallel to the long axis of the coupler face.

Comment: I'd add that its probably using this cord cause thats a beast of a PSU that draws a load of power [this is worth a read](http://www.jonnyguru.com/modules.php?name=NDReviews&op=Story&reid=175)

Comment: @JourneymanGeek, thank you! and... you mistyped the closing bracket in your comment.

Comment: This article says it has `Class-leading eight +12V rails with 110A (Peak up to 120A)`. 110 A - this is A LOT!

Answer (score 4):

Looks like you're looking for a [IEC 60320 C19](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEC_60320#C19.2FC20_coupler) to standard mains connector, like [so](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0012EK2RE). Of note, these cables are used commonly for things like UPS, server/rackmount equipment, etc.